# Is there a way to pass value to another root module

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a library project in which I have `pluginModule` and value is getting passed from `appModule` to it using forRoot. Please see my code below

**pluginModule**

```
export class pluginModule {
  public forRoot(configuration: pluginConfig): ModuleWithProviders<pluginModule > {
    return {
      ngModule: pluginModule 
      providers: [
        {
          provide: pluginConfig,
          useValue: configuration
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**appModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: ...,
  imports: [
    ...
    pluginModule.forRoot({
      pluginEnvironmentUrl: environment.pluginEnvironmentUrl // default value is getting passed
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: configureAuth, //I will be getting updated value for the environment.pluginEnvironmentUrl
      deps: ...,
      multi: true
    },
```

**configureAuth** const is making a call to service and get the updated value. This service resides inside angular project and not on the plugin

**service**

```
loadRuntimeConfig(): // observable
return this.http.get<RuntimeConfiguration>(`${appUrl}/${this.runtimeConfigJson}`, options).pipe(
      tap((config: RuntimeConfiguration) => {
        this.mapRuntimeConfig(config);
      }),
   );

mapRuntimeConfig(runtimeConfig: RuntimeConfiguration): void {
    environment.pluginEnvironmentUrl = runtimeConfig.pluginEnvironmentUrl;
    // QUESTION: is there any way to pass the above/updated value(environment.pluginEnvironmentUrl) 
    // to pluginModule from this place like below
    // pluginModule.forRoot({
    //  pluginEnvironmentUrl: environment.pluginEnvironmentUrl
    // })

 }
```

I tried to do this but the updated value is not getting passed. It's still taking the one which has been set at the module level.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite a value from your environment files..? environment.pluginEnvironmentUrl ?

Comment: @MikeOne Yes. you are right.

Comment: Right. So that is not going to work really as the environment file is simply a const that is imported there where you need it. It basically does not exist in memory at runtime so changing a value somewhere does not actually 'store' that value. To make this work you would need a service (singleton) that keeps the values available. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide something that can be updated. My idea is to use a loader that is able to provide you with the updated config at a later time, as you need.

```
export class PluginConfig {
  public pluginEnvironmentUrl: string = '';
  // add additional properties here if needed
}
```

The sample includes a default config that you might or might not need, but it is here to resemble your code

```
export class PluginModule {
  public static forRoot(
    configuration: PluginConfig
  ): ModuleWithProviders<PluginModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: PluginModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: PluginConfig,
          useValue: configuration,
        },
        {
          provide: PluginConfigLoader,
          useFactory: (defaultConfig: PluginConfig) =>
            new PluginConfigLoader(defaultConfig),
          deps: [PluginConfig],
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

The config loader is nothing but a class, that provides you the configuration through a public observable property, and can be initialized using the default config

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { PluginConfig } from './plugin-config.model';

export class PluginConfigLoader {
  private config$: BehaviorSubject<PluginConfig>;
  public configuration$: Observable<PluginConfig>;

  constructor(config: PluginConfig) {
    this.config$ = new BehaviorSubject(config);
    this.configuration$ = this.config$.asObservable();
  }

  loadConfig(config: PluginConfig) {
    this.config$.next(config);
  }
}
```

And inside the `AppModule` you can have this (nothing really changes from what you already have):

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    // ...
    PluginModule.forRoot({ pluginEnvironmentUrl: environment.pluginEnvironmentUrl }),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: configureAuth,
      deps: [ /* ... */ ],
      multi: true,
    },
  ]
})
```

You can inject the `PluginConfigLoader` inside your service and call the `load` method on it with the new config

```
this.pluginConfigLoader.load({
  pluginEnvironmentUrl: runtimeConfig.pluginEnvironmentUrl,
})
```

Then the config is available through the observable `ConfigurationLoader.configuration$`.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. Thank you. 
I tried to implement as you suggested, but getting  'No provider for PluginConfigLoader!' error which is being thrown from the service where we have `this.pluginConfigLoader.load`

Comment: I changed the place of calling the plugin loader load method and now I'm getting null error, 

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[CiamConfigLoader -> CiamConfigLoader -> CiamConfigLoader]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for CiamConfigLoader!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[CiamConfigLoader -> CiamConfigLoader -> CiamConfigLoader]: 
```

Comment: Can you try adding the `PluginConfigLoader` to the `deps` array of the `APP_INITIALIZER` provider? In the sample that I tested this, the `PluginConfigLoader` was a dependency of the factory function itself, and it worked this way. I figured it should also work if you require it in your service.